# Factory injection in Angular-Dart DI library

Tags: dependency-injection, dart, angular-dart

In my Dart application I'm using the MVP pattern and the angular-dart Dependency Injection library(angular-di).

In the example above, I cannot inject MyView or MyPresenter, as this is a circular dependency.

```dart
class MyView {
    MyPresenter presenter;
    MyView(this.presenter);
}
class MyPresenter {
    MyView view;
    MyPresenter(this.view);
}
```

The way I usually did this in Java with Guice was injecting a Factory, like:

```dart
class MyView {
    MyPresenter presenter;
    MyView(this.presenter);
}
class MyPresenter {
    Factory<MyView> factoryView;
    MyView view;
    MyPresenter(this.factoryView) {
        view = factoryView(this);
    }
}
```

How do I accomplish this using angular-di? Is there possible to inject the factory without having to write the factory itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Angular 2 Dart**

```
typedef MyView MyViewFactoryFn(MyPresenter p);
provide(MyView, useValue: (MyPresenter p) => new MyView(p));

MyPresenter(MyViewFactoryFn vf) {
  view = vf(this);
}
```

or

```
typedef MyView MyViewFactoryFn(MyPresenter p);

MyView viewFactory(MyPresenter p) => new MyView(p)
```

```
const Provider(MyView, useFactory: viewFactory);

MyPresenter(MyViewFactoryFn vf) {
  view = vf(this);
}
```

See also

- https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.core/Provider-class
- https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.core/provide

**Angular 1 Dart**

You can bind a closure

```dart
typedef MyView MyViewFactoryFn(MyPresenter p);
bind(MyView, toValue: (MyPresenter p) => new MyView(p));
```

the constructor should then look like

```dart
MyPresenter(MyViewFactoryFn vf) {
  view = vf(this);
}
```

There is also a `toFactory:` but I guess DI will call the factory itself but I guess `toValue:` with a closure could work (not tried though).

Comment: Sure, but that is not related to DI, that's just to make directives and components available to be used in the view.