# How do I use a component twice in a prent and child views (DI is shared and the comp is a singleton)

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have a button component (with app specific behavior) that i intended to use widely in the app. The issue is that when I have a parent/child views where I use this button, a click on the paren't button triggers the [action] of the child's view button : naturally you don't get what's happening if you don't have some years of object oriented programming. (which is pretty a bad point to get young school novices to use dart...)

Just to explain the problem : each component in dart is a singleton in its scope (the scope being different for each tree node, except for the parent/child relationship). This is a good optimisation practice, but I think there should be a mandatory attribute to the component that takes the values

```
scope="prototype|optimized"
```

This will iblige novices to understand the concepts behind it...

Is there a solution to get a new instance for each DI injection?

This is the code:

button.html

```
<img src="{{src}}" (click)="click()" (mouseover)="hover()" (mouseleave)="blur()"  class="imgBtn" />
```

button.dart

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';

@Component(
        selector: 'btn',
        templateUrl: 'button_comp.html',
        styleUrls: const['button_comp.css']
)
class ButtonComp {
    String src;
    Function btnAction;
    List<String> _srcList;
    @Input() bool disabled;

    @Input()
    void set sources(List<String> srcList) {
        if( srcList?.length != 3)
            print( 'there must be 3 files for the states : default, hover and clicked. Found :  ${srcList?.toString()} for ${btnAction.toString()}' );
        _srcList = srcList;
        src = srcList == null ? 'invalidState' : srcList[0];
    }

    @Input() set action(Function btnAction) {
        this.btnAction = btnAction;
    }

    void hover() {
        src = _srcList[1];
    }

    void blur() {
        src = _srcList[0];
    }

    void click() {
        src = _srcList[2];
        if( btnAction != null )
            this?.btnAction();
    }
}
```

Then I use this button in many places (knowing I can make it evolve through the app life)

For example

```
@Component(
  selector: 'users-comp',
  templateUrl: 'users_comp.html',
  styleUrls: const ['users_comp.css'],
    directives: const[ButtonComp, TextComp, InviteUsersDialogComp]
)
class UsersComp implements OnInit {
//...
}
```

If I have two buttons in UsersComp or one button in UsersComp and one in any of its children, then I will get the same instance of the button everywhere : I noticed that because clicking on the button of UsersComp triggered the 'action' of its subcomponents

users_comp.html

```
 <div class="titleDiv">
    <btn [action]="add"
         [sources]="['../images/addPerson.bmp', '../images/addPerson-h.bmp', '../images/addPerson-c.bmp']"
         class="addBtn"></btn>
    <div class="title">people</div>
```

and
invite-dialog-comp.html

```
<div class="modal-footer">
      <btn [action]="save(search.value)" [sources]="['../images/ok.bmp', '../images/ok-h.bmp', '../images/ok-c.bmp']" class="saveAdd"></btn>
    </div>
```

get the same button

Comment: Would you mind add some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish? I don't know if the suggestion I made in the other comment really applies.

Comment: Components are never singletons. Every button added to the DOM is a new different instance. The click might propagate. `click` is a DOM event and bubbles. You can try `(click)="click();$event.stopPropagation()"` to prevent bubbling. I can't see from your code how the components are used and how they are nested. Can you please add the parts of the components template that demonstrate that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this provider

```
provide('myFactory', useFactory: (dep1, dep2) => () => new Foo(dep1, dep2), deps: [Dep1, Dep2])
```

you can create new instances like

```
class MyComponent {
  MyClass(@Inject('myFactory') Function myFactory) {
    var prevInstance;
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var newInstance = myFactory();
      print('$i: ${identical(newInstance, prevInstance)}');
      prevInstance = newInstance;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer!, it seams there's hope. Can you please point me to a doc about the provider?

It seems you gave a reply to someone with another way of doing that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389693/factory-injection-in-angular-dart-di-library

Comment: I updated the answer you linked to. `provide()` can only be used where no const context is expected (for example `bootstrap(AppComponent, [provide(...)])`, however annotations like `@Component(...)` only allow constant values as parameters, and for that `const Provider(...)` has to be used.

Comment: Thanks!, there are too many new concepts for me here :-), I' mnot sure I can apply the solution immediately (I think it will be the case for other poeple who come to this question). 
Is there a way to cleanly hide the internals and delcare the component so we can use it in a standard manner @Component( directives: const [ViewFactory]) ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. `ViewFactory` doesn't sound like a component or directive. What do you mean with "standard manner"? `directives: const []` is just to tell the compiler which components and directives should be available in the view of this component when compiling the component.

Comment: I mean a way to hide the internals of the factory : this solution obliges us to pass a Buttonfactory, TabFactory, CaroussellFactory, etc.. to the constructor of each component that will use it: so we loose this automatic injection of parent/child directives mecanism.

I will mark your answer as a good answer, since you replyed on how to accomplish the task. But since you seam to be in ease with the dart angular architecture, I wanted to push your thoughts further for a more elegant solution :)

Comment: Actually I don't think I fully understand what your question is about. If you want to inject components, then you don't need providers. You also don't create component instances in factories. That's entirely useless. Components and directives need to be instantiated by Angular itself. Only plain classes can be instantiated the way I showed in my answer (or if you want, call them a service).

Comment: To be more specif (which may lead to a 'no way'), I was thinking about passing a 'magic' provider to the client components. This provider will intercept the moment angular needs it to return a copy of itself (by calling the factory method)... Or soehow hack the 'provider' mecanism so it will do a 'prototype' behavior instead of a singleton one

Comment: But if it is about components, there will be a new instances anyway.

Comment: Actually, my issue is that it seams I get the same instance of ButtonComp in the parent and child components

Comment: What do you mean with `get`? Do you inject `ButtonComp` somewhere?

Comment: Still trying to figure out what the actual problem is. What you can safely assume is, that every time `<btn ...>` occurs in your application, a new `ButtonComp` instance will be created. Perhaps there is something wrong with the `action` you pass around. This is not how it's usually done in Angular2. Either you use event binding `(action)="add($event)"` with an `@Output() EventEmitter action = new EventEmitter()` in the child component, or a shared service

Comment: (usually with a `Stream`) to notify other components about actions that happened, usually when the communicating components are not direct parent-child)

Comment: Sorry for the delay Gunter, I had sone stuff to do.

You're giving me good info. I don't know how it should be done. I just tried to combine what I understood from Angular Dart features to create a component.

I'm using the '@Input' action to set the function I want to be triggered on the component's client. 

If you have a better example with a '@output' and a stream for external event listening I'd be glad to see how you mean that.

Best regards and many htanks for your time

Comment: I don't think I'm even close to understand what you try to accomplish. It's just a detail that made me wonder. https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/tutorial/toh-pt6#!#streams shows how to use a stream in a service.

Comment: Ok I'll try to adapt the Widget with the '@output' mecanism
https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/api/angular2.core/Output-class

I was trying to put a function into the widget, that I trigger when the button is pressed.
Even if it's maybe not the standard system, I wonder why it behaves strangely.

Comment: I don't think it's an Angular issue. If you want, you can still do that. I just tried to point out that that's not the way it's normally done in Angular. I would need to see the full picture and perhaps have a running application where I can debug the problem. It's just hard to tell what might go wrong from a few code fragments.

Comment: Ok I think I was lost in the abstraction: I just added a (click)="action()" everywhere instead of trying to keep the action() function as a variable inside my directives (and change them dynamically if needed).

Now everything works, later I'll maybe have more knowledge and understand better what happened. the (click) output is now sufficient for my needs

Comment: Sounds reasonable. You can always selectively add this approach when you need more flexibility, but to get started it's usually a good idea to stick with the beaten path ;-) Hope you're unblocked now.